# Changing a view's state in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

**Goal:** I want to change my `progressBar's` visibility in RecyclerView to indicate that when a user adds an image with `addImage()`, the image is loading.

**Problem:** `addImage` is supposed to change `progressBar's` visibility. But, the Viewholder is not created when `addImage()` is called, so `progressBar`is undefined.

**MainActivity**:

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        if (getArguments().containsKey(PhotoFragment.IMAGE_URI)) {
            final Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(getArguments().getString(PhotoFragment.IMAGE_URI));
            galleryAdapter.addImage(imageUri);
            galleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getArguments().remove(PhotoFragment.IMAGE_URI);
        }
    }
```

**RecyclerView (where the problem resides)**:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.GalleryViewHolder> {


ArrayList<Uri> imageUriArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
File[] listFile;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private GalleryFragment mFragment;
private String airBnbDirectory = "/Airbnb";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

public GalleryAdapter(GalleryFragment fragment) {
    mFragment = fragment;
    loadSDCard();
}

public void addImage(final Uri imageUri) {
    imageUriArrayList.add(imageUri);

    //Save image in SD CARD(External Storage)
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        //
        String imageUriForLoadingSP;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("adapter", "OnPreExecute");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Cannot get progressBar because it's not created by the ViewHolder yet.
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            imageUriForLoadingSP = saveInSDCard(imageUri);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Log.d("mattSaving", "onPostExecute");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);


}




}

@Override
public GalleryAdapter.GalleryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.gallery_adapter_item, parent, false);
    return new GalleryAdapter.GalleryViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.GalleryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindView(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageUriArrayList.size();
}

public class GalleryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivPhoto;

    public GalleryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Log.d("adapter", "ViewHolder");
        ivPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    }

    public void bindView(final int position) {
        //load images called by addImage()
        Glide.with(mFragment)
                .load(imageUriArrayList.get(position)) // Uri of the picture
                .into(ivPhoto);

    }

}

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call notifyItemChanged(position) to update a view item.

```
public void addImage(final Uri imageUri) {
    imageUriArrayList.add(imageUri);

//Save image in SD CARD(External Storage)
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    //
    String imageUriForLoadingSP;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("adapter", "OnPreExecute");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Cannot get progressBar because it's not created by the ViewHolder yet.
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        imageUriForLoadingSP = saveInSDCard(imageUri);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.d("mattSaving", "onPostExecute");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);


}
```

You can put this notifyItemChanged(position); under the imageUriArrayList.add(imageUri); but you must provide a position, or you can try using notifyDataSetChanged there. Not sure how will that work.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to stick to the progressBar idea for learning purposes. Any ideas how to solve the issue without removing the progressBar?

Comment: I can now call progressBar without a null pointer exception! but the progressBar dosent seem to appear at the latest image I've added. Instead it appears in previously saved images, any clues why?

Comment: Can you update your current code? so I can see the changes?

Comment: I've added notifyDataSetChanged(); but I also tried notifyItemChanged(position) and they both yield the same result. What's odd too is that the progressBar seems to jump around from images to images whenever the ViewHolder is created again.

Comment: It is why I wanted to use notifyItemChanged(position) on these cases. notifyDataSetChanged tends to re - create the whole view list.

I think you should use notifyItemChanged(position) and check if the position is the last position to setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) for the progressbar.

Comment: I tried notifyItemChanged(position) and the same result still occurs. The progressBar seems to jump around to places when the RecylcerView is scrolled/view holder is re-created.